# How do I clear contents of cells = + in a range?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to clear the contents of any cell with a value equal to + in range C1:AG2500 but I'm not quite sure how to do it. could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: [`Range.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace).

Comment: @BigBen Thanks! got it figured out.